# Debugging java for loop that runs too many times

Tags: java

So I have some code,

```
public static int getNumberAtDigit(int source, int digit)
{
    if(digit > getSize(source))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "There aren't " + String.valueOf(digit) + " digits in " + String.valueOf(source) + ".");
    else
    {
        // Remove digits that come after what we want
        for(int i = getSize(source); i > digit; i--)
            source = (int) Math.floor(digit / 10);
        //Narrow it to only the last digit and return it
        return source % 10;
    }
}

public static int getSize(long d)
{
    String numberS = String.valueOf(d);
    return numberS.length();
}
```

and when I run `System.out.println(getNumberAtDigit(4532, 3));` it returns 0 but when I run `System.out.println(getNumberAtDigit(4532, 4));` it returns 2, like it should. I have tested and know that the method `getSize(long d)` isn't the culprit and works as normal. I believe the for loop is running too many times but cannot figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply use `digit / 10` instead of `(int) Math.floor(digit / 10)`?

Comment: Also note that What is inputted to `source` and the loop counter `i` won't make business to what is returned unless `digit >= getSize(source)`: only `digit` determines what is returned for `digit < getSize(source)`

Comment: To make sure that it doesn't round up when it divides, but since you commented that I assume it automatically rounds down.

Comment: If `digit > getSize(source)` then it throws the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and if `digit == getSize(source)` then the code should and does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
source = (int) Math.floor(digit / 10);
```

If the value of `digit` is less than 10, this function will always return 0. I believe what you meant to do is use `Math.floor(source / 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

It should have been `source = (int) Math.floor(source / 10);`, not `source = (int) Math.floor(digit / 10);` because I don't care what `digit / 10` is. I'm so smart :)